# Error inflating a layout

Tags: android, inflate-exception

My loginScreen is not displayed in Emulator.It is shown as Your application has been Stooped.I have a XML File which is layout is perfect position in design form.I having login_screen.xml  like: 
please help me.I will display the same login_screen xml file in my emulator.I try to make LoginScreen in manifest file also then also its giving same error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/black" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relMyHead"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@drawable/loginimage">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_userName"
            android:layout_width="260dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/img_login_logo"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/envelope"
            android:drawablePadding="14dp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/envelope"
            android:hint="@string/Email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/blue_500"
            android:textColorHint="#BBBBBB">

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_password"
            android:layout_width="260dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edt_userName"
            android:layout_below="@+id/edt_userName"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/key"
            android:drawablePadding="14dp"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:password="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textColorHint="#BBBBBB" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_Login"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edt_password"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/edt_password"
            android:layout_below="@+id/edt_password"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/loginimage"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:letterSpacing="0.1"
            android:text="@string/btn_login"

            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:foregroundTintMode="screen" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_login_logo"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:minHeight="500dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/csrlogo_2x" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/new_user_reg_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btn_Login"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:longClickable="false">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                android:letterSpacing="0.1"
                android:text="@string/not_member"

                android:textColor="@color/barLightColor"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/register"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:clickable="true"

                android:letterSpacing="0.1"
                android:textColor="@color/popup_text_color"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/img_login_logo"

            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
            android:letterSpacing="0.2"
            android:text="TRAVEL ASSIST"
            android:textColor="@color/popup_text_color"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Error log :

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class <unknown>
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393)
     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166)
     at com.example.developer.travelassistmobileapp.LoginScreen.onCreate(LoginScreen.java:51)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class <unknown>
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166) 
     at com.example.developer.travelassistmobileapp.LoginScreen.onCreate(LoginScreen.java:51) 
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: I have checked your code it is perfectly working for me.. i have changed all drawables and removed fonts for testing.. so try to check all your resources used in this if any of them are vectors then post it.. or just clean rebuild

Comment: @giri probably in your java you calling wrong xml name

Answer (score 0):

Change this part like this  :

BEFORE:

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_userName"
            android:layout_width="260dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/img_login_logo"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/envelope"
            android:drawablePadding="14dp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/envelope"
            android:hint="@string/Email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/blue_500"
            android:textColorHint="#BBBBBB">

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
```

AFTER:

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_userName"
            android:layout_width="260dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/img_login_logo"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/envelope"
            android:drawablePadding="14dp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/envelope"
            android:hint="@string/Email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/blue_500"
            android:textColorHint="#BBBBBB">
        </EditText>
```

Comment: check with the resources you have used.